# How to draw flowchart for code involving opening from text file and reading them

Tags: c, windows, flowchart

like this code

```
  fp1=fopen("Fruit.txt","r");
  if(fp1==NULL)
  {
       printf("ERROR in opening file\n");
       return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)//reads Fruits.txt database
    {
    fgets(product,sizeof(product),fp1);
    id[i]=atoi(strtok(product,","));
    strcpy(name[i],strtok(NULL,","));
    price[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));
    stock[i]=atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
    }
  }
  fclose(fp1);
```

These symbols sound too similar to differentiate their function,can anyone helps me by any method, or use names of shape according to this site http://www.breezetree.com/article-excel-flowchart-shapes.htm

Comment: sorry forgot to indent

Comment: I don't see any relation at all between your own code and "a flowchart". What is supposed to be in this `fruit.txt` and how is this related to flowcharts?

Comment: @Jongware this is whats inside the txt: id,name,price,stock

Comment: @MartinJames i googled froot loops and i see cereal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Flow chart]

---

**REF:**

Used a random online tool to generate this flowchart from your code. http://code2flow.com/

Study more about flowcharts here : http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/flowchart-guide-flowchart-tutorial/

See sample flowcharts here : http://www.conceptdraw.com/samples/flowcharts

Comment: thank you very much !! do you know when we need to use these kind of symbols? 'database'(cylinder shape), 'document','stored data'

Comment: database(cylinder) is used to display db interactions with the system.

Comment: Read this : http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/flowchart-guide-flowchart-tutorial/

Comment: @problematic No you don't

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days of FORTRAN, we used that hexagonal symbol on the page you linked to for the "DO" loop, which is basically the same as the modern "for" loop.

So, to draw the loop part of your program I would use that symbol, with a note inside like this:
  for i = 0 --> (lines - 1)
Read this as "for i from 0 to (lines - 1)" with the increment of 1 implied by default.
Then the bottom-most box in the loop would have two arrows coming out of it: one straight down to the next statement, and one out the side heading back up to the side of the hexagon.

You could use the diamond to represent "if", but that can obscure the meaning of what you are trying to do, namely execute the loop a certain number of times.

BTW, I don't have high enough reputation yet to post images, so you will have to either follow the link or visualize a hexagon whose center section has been stretched horizontally.

Update: I see that, while I was typing my answer, thecbuilder has also answered this, with a real flowchart. His illustrates how the loop actually works internally, which is fine; mine was intended to show the meaning of the loop on a slightly higher level of abstraction.

Comment: did u delete ur answer? can you upload to photobucket or other method and share the link here? thanks for trying to help, i appreciate ur effort!

Comment: @problematic : Because my reputation is not >= 50, this site says I cannot post a comment above, but I can post one here. anyway, to expand on the question of the cylinder flowchart symbol meaning 'database', 'document', or 'stored data', all can be correct. See next comment...

Comment: ...continued. This is again an issue of what what level of abstraction you are working at. if your program is reading a file directly from a disk, you can represent this with the cylinder, in which case you might label the cylinder 'local or networked drive'. But if your program is accessing a database through a separate server, you could again use the cylinder but label it 'SQL server'.

Comment: OK, here is a link to my version of the flowchart. [link](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~ciaraldi/loopchart.png)

Comment: By the way, the way you have written this code, I hope that the variable 'name' is declared char* name[MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRUITS], so each element of the array points to a C-style string, and MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRUITS is a symbolic constant containing the maximum number of lines in the file. Then before you ever enter this loop, you have malloc'd a series of character arrays, each big enough to hold the longest possible name (plus one for the null terminator). Otherwise you will be trying to strcpy into some random place in memory. continued...

Comment: A better approach might be to NOT pre-allocate the space for the names, but instead use strdup(), which allocates the right amount of memory for you. Like this: name[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",")); As I have to keep reminding my intro C students: C does not work by magic -- if you want to store something somewhere, especially an array (which is all a string is in C), you have to allocate memory for it.